# Retrieving data from SQLite and display it into a ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a problem with this code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
       adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_view_medication, cursor, from, toViewMed)
```

When I run my project, the logcat shows this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;

    // Get ListView object from xml
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Create_Alarm();
    populateListView();
}

public void populateListView(){

    myDb.getAllData();
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllData();

    String[] from = new String[] {myDb.COL_2, myDb.COL_3 };
    int[] toViewMed = new int[] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtQuantity};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_view_medication, cursor, from, toViewMed) {

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            //return null;
            return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_view_medication, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            // Find fields to populate in inflated template
            TextView medicine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            TextView quantity= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);

            // Extract properties from cursor
            String  from = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("from"));
            int toViewMed = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("toViewMed"));

            // Populate fields with extracted properties
            medicine.setText(from);
            quantity.setText(String.valueOf(toViewMed));

        }
    };

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: The error says that your table doesn't have a column called "_id"

Answer (score 0):

CursorAdapters **need** an `_id` column, because they rely on it.
Quick fix: add to your query `... , rowID AS _id, ...` (not the dots, obviously)

`rowID` is a special "automatic" field which is indeed a replacement for a missing `_id` field.

As per the [official docs](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> In SQLite, table rows normally have a 64-bit signed integer ROWID which is unique among all rows in the same table. (WITHOUT ROWID tables are the exception.)
>
> You can access the ROWID of an SQLite table using one of the special column names ROWID, *ROWID*, or OID. Except if you declare an ordinary table column to use one of those special names, then the use of that name will refer to the declared column not to the internal ROWID.
>
> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID using any of four different names, the original three names described above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any context.

Comment: I have changed that code like this:                                                        **public Cursor getAllData(){
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select rowid _id,* from TABLE_NAME", null);     **                                                                                                         
    return cursor;}

Comment: No. It should be: `... db.rawQuery("select rowid _id, from " + TABLE_NAME, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your database too.

Try this

Example:

**MyDatabase.java**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final rowid_id="_id";
       ......

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + rowid_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,Name TEXT,Weather TEXT, Date DATETIME, Status Text, TimeIn_Info DATE TIME, TimeOut_Info DATETIME)");
```